# HTML FORM not all being passed to print_r($_POST)

Tags: html, forms

For some reason I can't get my form to work. There isn't anything too complex. I've tried different variations with no luck. I have also tried to manually fill in the value="value" and it still cannot get passed into the $_POST.

The only variables that are in the variable $_POST is my submit button and my "owes" radio button.

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"  class="asholder">
    <div style="float:right">Hidden ID Field: <input type="text" id="userID" value="" style="font-size: 10px; width: 20px;" disabled="disabled" /></div>    
    <input style="width: 200px" type="text" id="personinput" value="" placeholder="Person" /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="owes" value="sUser" placeholder="Who Owe's Who?" /> owes me
    <input type="radio" name="owes" value="mUser" /> I owe them <br />
    <input style="width: 200px" type="text" id="amount" value="" placeholder="Amount of..." /><br />
    <textarea style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" id="comment" value="" placeholder="Comment"></textarea><br /> 

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Throw a Ching" id="submit">Throw a Ching</button>
</form>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the other fields a name attribute. The button and the radio have name filled in so they show up. Your other fields don't.

Comment: That did help. Thanks. But now they all show up aside from my hidden field. That needs to be posted as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Nevermind got it to work by changing the type to hidden and removing disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your input types should have a name attribute something like this

```
<input type="text" name="sample" id="sample" placeholder="type here" />
```

Please take note that attribute "name" is used as a key/index to able to pass to the script file

Comment: Your code snippet appear to be syntactically wrong? What is the id attribute value? I guess you did a typo.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. it should be
<input type="text" name="sample" id="sample" placeholder="type here" />

Comment: You can always edit your answer to rectify it. Please do so whenever you feel a post can be edited.